# Is there a way to run one single test with Chutzpah?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chutzpah

Fairly straightforward -- Can I run a single test with Chutzpah JavaScript test runner, via the command line tool, or other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chutzpah will always run the whole test file, not an individual test. I have thought about providing a way to do the single test but there is not a way at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can your provide more context around this? Is there a Github issue or something you can direct me to?